# How to calculate nchar in R?

Tags: r, char

I try the following code

```
j <- "*Politics:* Disgraced peer Jeffrey Archer is set to make \xa31m from his Belmarsh "
nchar(j)
# Error in nchar(j) : invalid multibyte string 1
```

and as you can see I am not able to use nchar(). How can I work around this?

Comment: Why can't you use `nchar`? Do you get an error when you do? If so, what error? What number of characters *do* you get out and what do you *expect* to get out?

Comment: What code did you use?  What was the error?  Posting the code you used is much more helpful and likely to get a response than a picture of part of what you did.

Comment: Yes, I get an error. I set the character as x and write nchar(x). An error is showed by R with no result.

Comment: Please post the exact code you used in your question.  Include the character string you tried.

Comment: I edited your question to be much easier for people to help with.  If I messed something up feel free to edit it but I highly recommend that you don't post things as images that don't need to be images and that you always include the error output of interest.

Comment: Thanks Dason! That's what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the specific encoding you can use `iconv` to convert to something a little nicer to work with

```
j <- "*Politics:* Disgraced peer Jeffrey Archer is set to make \xa31m from his Belmarsh "
iconv(j, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")
#[1] "*Politics:* Disgraced peer Jeffrey Archer is set to make £1m from his Belmarsh "
nchar(iconv(j, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8"))
#[1] 79
```

I wrote your text to a file and used geany to check the encoding which is how I arrived at ISO-8859-1.

An alternative route that doesn't require you to figure out the encoding is to use `type="bytes"` instead of manually converting to UTF-8

```
nchar(j, type = "bytes")
#[1] 79
```

I would suggest reading the help file on nchar `?nchar` as there are slight differences between the default type and type="bytes".

Comment: I think this is the problem, I was thinking the escape character was the issue.

Comment: Your alternative route of counting the bytes will only work if the encoding uses one byte per character - which you can only understand if you can figure out the encoding!

Answer (score 2):

If Dason's correct...

There's only one way I know of to do this and it requires reading each string in with `readLines`:

```
x <- readLines(n=2)
*Politics:* Disgraced peer Jeffrey Archer is set to make \xa31m from his Belmarsh 
df vetf tefer\x vtgr
nchar(x)
```

The n=2 tells R you're reading in 2 lines.
Then read them in (I used <kbd>contr</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> in rgui or <kbd>cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> in R studio).
Then you can use `nchar`

Comment: A down vote really wasn't warranted here in that I was providing an answer to a minimal question.  The solution works for what I believed at the time was the problem.  I answered before Dason answered, the Dason comment was regarding his edits to the OP's ambiguous question.  The original didn't even have code but a picture of the text. After Dason's response I left it up to (a) be informative and (b) because the OP never edited their response (Dason did) to be clear so the actual problem is unknown.    All I ask is that you put 4 or more seconds of thought into a vote as this isn't facebook.

Comment: This may help you vote better in the future: [-voting explained LINK-](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)